# Using WordPress plugins for custom post types?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to  add a simple light box plugin for my images gallery. Images are being fetched in a template called gallery-template like this

```
<?php
    $args=array('post_type' => 'gallery');
    $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
    while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

        <h1 class="product_txt"><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <a href=''><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'product_img') );?></a>

     </div>
     <?php                                
    endwhile;
 ?>
```

I've seen many plugins but they ask to add images to pages instead of  getting them from a template, so how  can I make it work like this?

Comment: What's the problem? What's it not doing that you want it to?

Comment: Just enqueue lightbox jquery, add `data-lightbox` to your images, and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without plugin. Use any lightbox you want. My example is with prettyphoto.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
<?php
    $args=array('post_type' => 'gallery');
    $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
    while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

        <?php   // Get image url
                $attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($query->ID), 'full' );
                $url = $attachment['0']; ?>

        <h1 class="product_txt"><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <a rel='prettyPhoto' href='<?php echo $url; ?>'><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'product_img') );?></a>

     </div>
     <?php                                
    endwhile;
 ?>
```